# KeystoneJS and naming?

Tags: keystonejs

I'm new to Keystone JS and NodeJS. 
This is the Part I totally do not understand;
Example 'Post' as defined as 'Post', but there are no 'posts', but when I call/ search for Post, in example (and my practices), it was 'posts'.
Exp:

```
keystone.set('nav', {
    posts: ['posts', 'post-categories'],
    enquiries: 'enquiries',
    users: 'users',
});
```

Similar 'PostCategory' => 'post-categories', 'Enquiry'=>'enquiries' etc.

But when I making new Routes=>View for my custom post type, I must use:

```
locals.data = {
    food: []
};
```

At this, its 'food' not 'foods'.

Answer (score 0):

Keystone automatically uses the plural form of your model names in the Admin Panel, instead of its singular name. It's still referred to by its singular name (Food, PostCategory, Enquiry, etc.) throughout your code, but the admin panel uses the plural forms if referring to multiple documents of a model.

When working with `local`, you can name the properties of that object anything you want. Doesn't have to be `locals.data.food`; it can be whatever you want.

Also, the plural form of food is food. So nothing will change when using the plural form of a `Food` model in your Admin Panel.

Comment: So what If I use random name without plural name ? Like a code or something does not in english dictionary, like 'kappa' or 'monanngon'.

Comment: I think it will just add "s" to the end of the word.

Comment: Modern Keystone (v6) uses pluralize (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pluralize) for this but the version this question was originally for (probably v5?, now called Keystone Classic) used the inflect package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/i). See those packages for specific docs. Keystone v6 also lets you specify specific plural terms if you prefer, see https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/lists#graphql.